# Pie Chart Label Confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to visualize data stored in  `data_dict`.

Some part of my code is copy+paste from [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-pie-and-donut-labels-py) examples. Even I did what I wanted to get from code. I couldn't figure out how `wedges, texts, autotexts = axpie(....)` work. Expecially how wedges, texts and autotexts part assign.

Is there anybody can share any amount of information about those lines with me for my further work.

Confusion part;

```
wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(value_list, autopct=lambda pct: self.text_func(pct, value_list), textprops=dict(
            color="w"))
```

Here is full of my code;

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=5, dpi=100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi, tight_layout=True)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.plot_data()

        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def text_func(self, pct, all_val):
        absolute = int(pct/100.*np.sum(all_val))
        return "{:.1f}%\n({:d})".format(pct, absolute)

    def plot_data(self):
        data_dict = {'10': '88', '9': '31', '8': '11', '7': '5', '6': '2', '5': '4'}

        key_list = []
        value_list = []
        mass_list = []
        for i, j in data_dict.items():

            key_list.append(int(i))
            value_list.append(int(j))

            mass = int(i)*int(j)
            mass_list.append(mass)

        average = round(sum(mass_list) / sum(value_list), 2)
        print(key_list)
        print(value_list)
        print(average)

        ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.clear()
        wedges, texts, autotexts = ax.pie(value_list, autopct=lambda pct: self.text_func(pct, value_list), textprops=dict(
            color="w"))

        ax.legend(wedges, key_list, title="Points", fontsize="8", loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, 0, 0.5, 1))

        ax.set_title("This is title")

        self.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Canvas()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: They are what `ax.pie` returns. https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie

Comment: it seems `ax.pie` uses `return value1, value2, value3` and this is why when you do `wedges, texts, autotexts = axpie(....)` then it does `wedges, texts, autotexts = value1, value2, value3` and it measn `wedges = value1` and `texts = value2` and `autotexts = value3`